# Pytrends raises error 500 on script, works on iPython

Tags: python, ipython

I have a list of terms I want to query on Google Trends using `pytrends` (version 4.7.3), say `queries = ['bitcoin', 'covid', 'granola', 'water', 'amazon books', 'chocolate', 'bluetooth', 'fountain pen']`. I have the following script:

```
import datetime as dt
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

queries = ['bitcoin', 'covid', 'granola', 'water', 'amazon books', 'chocolate', 'bluetooth', 'fountain pen']

def today():
    return dt.date.today().isoformat()

def yesterday():
    return (dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=1)).isoformat()

trends_region = {}

pytrend = TrendReq()

for kw in queries:
    pytrend.build_payload(kw_list = [kw], timeframe=f'{yesterday()} {today()}')
    trends_region[kw] = pytrend.interest_by_region(resolution='COUNTRY')
```

When I run this in the terminal, or on iPython with `%run script.py`, I get `pytrends.exceptions.ResponseError: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 500.`; however, when I do it step by step on iPython I do get the data I want (a dictionary whose values are data frames). By "step by step" I mean defining the list `queries`, the functions `today` and `yesterday`, the empty dictionary `trends_region` and typing in the `for` loop. There are many issues open with similar errors at the module's GitHub site, for example [here](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/371) and [here](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/368), but perhaps someone here knows why this happens.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how you could run that code without it throwing an exception before it even gets to the point where you're getting that 500 error; you have `dt.date.today` instead of `dt.date.today()` and `dt.deltatime` instead of `dt.timedelta`. Please post the code you're actually running, as it seems you may have written this from memory without actually running it, instead of copying and pasting it. When I fixed those things and ran the code, there was no error or output at all, but when I used a debugger, it looks like `trends_region` got filled with the correct data.

Comment: Thanks @RandomDavis; indeed, I had some typos which I edited out. So you ran the script as "main" (e.g. `python3 script.py`) and didn't get an error?

Comment: I pasted your code straight into PyCharm and clicked run after fixing the obvious typos. No errors, seemed to work fine. Using Python 3.9 and the latest version of `pytrends`.